# How to position menu on toolbar using inflateMenu?

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, toolbar, android-toolbar

So I'm trying to create a menu on a toolbar using the inflateMenu method. The items are added from the right side by default. Is there any way to position the menu items manually? I want to make them spread equally across the page.

Here's my code:

MainActivity.Java

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/about"
        android:title="About"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/help"
        android:title="Help"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

[image]